# I have declared n in the function but it is giving me n is undentified error after I compile the code and try to run

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
// Write a function named print_out that prints all the whole numbers from 1 to N.
// by calling a function.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function must be declared before being used.

void::print_out(int n);

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> n;

    print_out(n);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

// Print-out function.
// Prints numbers from 1 to n. 

int print_out(n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)     // For i = 1 to n,
        cout << i << " ";        //   print i
    return n;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'print_out' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  
Error   2   error C2065: 'n' : undeclared identifier    
Error   3   error C2448: 'print_out' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition   
    4   IntelliSense: identifier "n" is undefined   
    5   IntelliSense: identifier "n" is undefined
```

Comment: it should be `int print_out(int n)`, the parameter and the variable in main are two separate entities.

Comment: It gives me Error: Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone. When I put in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your function like this:

```
void print_out(int); //Takes an int argument, and 'void' specifies it has no return value
```

And it should be defined with the same return type as the header:

```
void print_out(int n) { //is a 'void' type function as previously declared
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)     //We can declare 'i' in the for loop like this
        cout << i << " ";    
    //Note we're not returning a value: It's a 'void' function.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are simple syntax mistakes:

```
// void::print_out(int n); //// :: is the scope operator.
vpid print_out(int n);

// int print_out(n) {  //// the type must still be there.
void print_out(int n) {
```

Fix these and it compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e95fb196ad1fed2d

Comment: but it has to be a void its asking me to be. It says the print_out function should have type void; it does not return a value.